# Are run-time type checks normal in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

New to objective-c.  When I write code in strongly-typed OO languages, I like to make my design as explicit as possible in the code, I also like to make sure that I'm maintaining program correctness by checking parameter value ranges, etc (for example, at the beginning of a method make sure that an object reference is not null, use constants as much as possible..).  These simple checks, have helped my colleagues and I to catch issues during dev time.

Now working in objective-c, I'm really tempted to check to make sure that a selector is supported before sending a message to a protocol implementation.  Or manually check for type compatibility of objects in an `NSArray`.

Are these types of checks normal in objective-c programs?  When do you deem these checks necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assert statements are common to crash early (NSAssert, NSParameterAssert, NSCParameterAssert, NSCAssert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is totally acceptable, although not necessarily the bread and butter of every programmer's approach. (I don't always do this, although perhaps I should.)

The way you'd check would be like so:

```
if([someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someSelector)]){
  [someObject someSelector];
}
```

If you send a message to an object that it doesn't respond to, you'll get a runtime crash. If you check ahead of time, your logic might be totally off. (A common example is when you think you're dealing with one object, when you are in fact, working with something entirely different. This introduces the tradeoff between crashes during development versus expected values/behavior at runtime.

If you code carefully, you'll go a lot farther than verbose checking.

**Edit:**

Thinking about your question a little more, the runtime also offers the `conformsToProtocol:` method, which allows you to check if a class or an instance conforms to a protocol. This would seem to be exactly what you want.

A place where this is actually essential to not crashing, no matter how careful you are, is when you add support for new iOS features while maintaining backwards compatibility. (In such cases you weak link against new frameworks and use these very same checks to ensure compatibility.

As others have noted, you do get some form of compile-time checking when it comes to protocols. If a method isn't denoted as `@optional`, the Xcode will warn you of an incomplete implementation.

Comment: @Jano I've thought about it, and there's the issue which I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the protocol definition declares the method as `@required` checking would be redundant, if it's `@optional` checking it's a must. Checking the object's type in arrays is probably good practice if you want a bulletproof code (however, it may have some performance drawbacks), but I never did it myself, although I usually work alone and rather name my arrays suggestively than checking types.

Answer (score 1):

About protocols, if you declare a method as `@optional`, the implementation is optional, so you should check wether the object actually responds to the selector (usually you cache the result of the check instead of checking it on every invocation). If it's not optional, don't test. The compiler will emit warnings for not implemented selectors, so runtime checking really isn't required if all you want to do is to fail anyways (the runtime will throw an exception and the debugger will break, so you will know what is missing anyways).

About checking objects inside an array, you can do it, but usually if you don't want to accept every object, you don't export the array itself but a method like `addMyObject:(AllowedObject *)object`. Obviously, if you accept an array as parameter and want to make sure that all the objects inside of it conform, you should check the object (either when you iterate over the array, or by calling something like `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` on it and checking if the returned `NSIndexSet` has the same count as the array (or you can just take the `NSIndexSet` and get the subarray described by it from the original array and then work with it), depending on what you need).

However, due to Objective-Cs runtime, you don't necessarily have to check every method invocation. If it's not supported, the debugger will break and you can determine what's wrong. It's however a good practice to check your parameters vor validity via the `NSAssert` macros (and write unit tests if you aren't already doing that, they will also save you a lot of headache at one point!).